# Activiti bpmn - missing variable comparision to false

Tags: activiti, bpmn

In my `BPMN` file I have an `gateway` defined as follows:

```
<exclusiveGateway id="gateway" name="An gateway"/>

<sequenceFlow id="sequence1" sourceRef="gateway"
        targetRef="task1">
    <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression">${variableABC == true}
    </conditionExpression>
</sequenceFlow>

<sequenceFlow id="sequence2" sourceRef="gateway"
        targetRef="task2">
        <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression">${variableABC == false}
    </conditionExpression>
</sequenceFlow>
```

I wonder what is going to happen when **the variable `variableABC` is missing** (not set in the workflow engine)?

From my tests it seems that the flow will go to second branch. Could anyone explain why?

In Java `null == false` would throw an exception (?). How does activiti engine works in this situation? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, it will go to the **Second path** if no value is provided. **by default** value of `boolean` is always `false`. it's a common java logic. for **String**, If no default path is provided then `null` value of expression, Activiti will throw an exception saying - no path/default found after Gateway.

Comment: You get exception from activiti (JUEL) unless there is defined process/execution variable, spring bean or java delegate resolving to variableABC.

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin user is asking if he does not set the process variable explicitly. Please get thorough understanding of question before judging.

Comment: if he does not set process variable, he gets org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Unknown property used in expression: ${variableABC == true}
If he gets something else, there is more to the story - variable is set in start map or defined before

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin - by `set the process variable` we are taking about setting the `value` of process variable, not creating a process variable. if he does not provide a process variable, sure it will throw a ActivitiException :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to deploy the workflow similar to above one, but I am not able to deploy it. Its giving me an error

**org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Unknown property used in expression: ${variableABC == true}**

then I changed it to

**[CDATA[${execution.getVariable('variableABC') == true}]]**

**[CDATA[${execution.getVariable('variableABC') == false}]]**

**[CDATA[${execution.getVariable('variableABC') == null}]]**

After this I was able to  deploy it and run my tests successfully.

**Observations:**

1. It has never gone to "false" sequence flow when I had above 3 sequence  flow
2. When I removed last sequence flow i.e. checking with null, I got error 
   **org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: No outgoing sequence flow of the exclusive gateway 'exclusivegateway1' could be selected for continuing the process**

So I think there is no issue with activiti. You just verify your workflow properly.

:)

Comment: You can also refer to [Exclusive Gateways](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnExclusiveGateway)

Comment: Whatever answer you have given, Same thing I explained with proper error messages.

Comment: You will get deployment error if you define no expression at all, but unfortunately, you can still deploy process with expression refering to undefined variable. It's runtime error that happens when the process is being executed.

Comment: @SachinMesare why to try when you already know the logic ;). moreover you just complicated the answer i think.

Comment: I thought it will be better to provide exact errors that occurred. And it was a minutes job for me to run the test case as I already have all the setup, as I am working on it :)